# Get referenced cell and sheet for data validation value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a list of `Foods` in a Google Sheet.

[image]

On another sheet I reference A2:A100 to create a data validation list to select from.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to auto-fill the equivalent columns on the other sheet depending on which food is selected but the value in the data validation list is simply text, so I cannot figure out how to get the row it is on to transfer the values onto the new sheet.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

This is what I am trying to get it to look like:

[image]

If I change any of the foods, I want columns B - H to automatically fill in with the correct values from the `Foods` sheet.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use couple of methods

Using `DGET`

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(DGET('Foods'!$A$1:$K$100,{"calories","sat","poly","mono","fiber","carbs","protein"},{"Food";$A2})))
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(DGET('Foods'!$A$1:$K$100,{$B$1,$C$1,$D$1,$E$1,$F$1,$G$1,$H$1},{"Food";$A2})))
```

Using `VLOOKUP`

```
=IFNA(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($A2,'Foods'!$A$1:$K$100,{5,6,7,8,9,10,11},FALSE)))
```

Place the formula on cell `B1` and drag down.

Functions used:

- [`DGET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094148)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)